# Cloudfront Path Pattern redirect without changing url

Tags: amazon-cloudfront, aws-lambda-edge

I have the main site running on `https://example.com` via CloudFront and elasticbeanstalk environment. I also have a blog site running on an ec2 server at URL `https://blog.example.com`.

Now what I want to do is to create a path pattern such that when someone navigates to `https://example.com/blog/` it serves blog content without actually changing URL to `https://blog.example.com`

I created a behavior pattern on CloudFront for path `/blog/*` but when it redirects it changes URL to `https://blog.example.com`

Answer (score 0):

A path pattern of `/blog/*` pointing to your blog as the origin will work, just point directly to the EC2 hostname as the origin. If that is giving you a redirect, you'll need to pinpoint where the redirect is coming from. It could be coming from your blog that is sending a 301/302 redirect through CloudFront.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I noticed that for url like `https://example.com/blog/` it maintains url but when clicking on any blog or something inside wordpress it swithces url to `https://blog.example.com/blahblah`